# Django: List of symbols for templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Not really a direct coding question, but still something I wasn't able to find on my own ... and related to coding ;)

Is there any list which symbols/placeholders are available in a Django template? So e.g. `{{user}}` etc.

Comment: The only things that are available in templates are those that you pass yourself and those that are added by the context processors.

Comment: Maybe some additional project to create a list which processor is providing which symbol ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [list of built-in filters and tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/), in addition the default template context processors add the following:

- `{{ user }}` and `{{ perms }}` from `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`
- `{{ debug }}` and `{{ sql_queries }}` from `django.core.context_processors.debug`
- `{{ LANGUAGES }}` and `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}` from `django.core.context_processors.i18n`
- `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` from `django.core.context_processors.media`
- `{{ STATIC_URL }}` from `django.core.context_processors.static`
- `{{ csrf_token }}` from `django.core.context_processors.csrf`
- `{{ request }}` from `django.core.context_processors.request`
- `{{ messages }}` from `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages`

Answer (score 1):

A list of built in tags and filters?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/

EDIT: still not sure what you mean by symbols. `{{user}}` is not a symbol, it is a template variable.

Perhaps you could refer to the code itself: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/context_processors.py

Comment: I've seen them. but was looking für symbols provided by processors

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/) and [django-template-debug](https://django-template-debug.readthedocs.org/) which provide this functionality for debugging purposes.

Comment: I'm looking more for kind of documentation

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Both of these projects are well documented. This info is provided by the Template panel http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/panels.html#template in django-debug-toolbar and the variables tag https://django-template-debug.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_templates/variables.html#variables in django-template-debug. The context of a general template can't be documented by Django, only by the author of the view.